# How to contrast stretch multiple bands Geotiff in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

In Openlayers,I want to realize render multiple bands Geotiff by Contrast Stretch Min and Max.
Like by QGIS or Geoserver using SLD:

```
<sld:RasterSymbolizer>
<sld:ChannelSelection>
  <sld:RedChannel>
    <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
    <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
      <sld:Normalize>
        <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">-3.509304523468</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">701.02770996094</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:Normalize>
    </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
  </sld:RedChannel>
  <sld:GreenChannel>
    <sld:SourceChannelName>2</sld:SourceChannelName>
    <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
      <sld:Normalize>
        <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">12.172845840454</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">20.350427627563</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:Normalize>
    </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
  </sld:GreenChannel>
  <sld:BlueChannel>
    <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
    <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
      <sld:Normalize>
        <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">-3.509304523468</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">701.02770996094</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:Normalize>
    </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
  </sld:BlueChannel>
</sld:ChannelSelection>
<sld:ContrastEnhancement/>
</sld:RasterSymbolizer>
```

I have seen the examples like https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-stretch.html and
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-style.html.

But I dit not find the method which I need.
Can you help me ? Appreciate any clues or suggestions.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to replicate that SLD

Either let OpenLayers normalize it and use the default RGBA style.  As each band has different min and max values the url will need to be loaded multiple tiles

```
const rMin = -3.509304523468;
const rMax = 701.02770996094;

const gMin = 12.172845840454;
const gMax = 20.350427627563;

const bMin = -3.509304523468;
const bMax = 701.02770996094;

const source = new GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      bands: [1],
      min: rMin,
      max: rMax,
      url: url,
    },
    {
      bands: [2],
      min: gMin,
      max: gMax,
      url: url,
    },
    {
      bands: [3],
      min: bMin,
      max: bMax,
      url: url,
    },
  ],
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: source,
});
```

Or normalize it between the min and max values for each band yourself, which should be more efficient

```
function normalize(band, min, max) {
  return [
    '/',
    ['-', ['clamp', ['band', band], min, max], min],
    ['-', max, min],
  ];
}

const source = new GeoTIFF({
  normalize: false,
  sources: [
    {
      url: url,
    },
  ],
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: source,
  style: {
    color: [
      'array',
      normalize(1, rMin, rMax),
      normalize(2, gMin, gMax),
      normalize(3, bMin, bMax),
      1,
    ],
  },
});
```

Comment: Hello Mike, thank you for your reply.I have tried your solutions and it can solve my problem.Thank you very much.